# make custom item for each recyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm newbie in android and I want to make custom item for each recyclerView item. In one item of rv there might be several linearLayouts with data. Initial I added linear layout to item of rv one by one. But in the process layouts of another item is duplication in item.

This is the onBind function of my Adapter class.

```
fun onBind(letterItem: LetterItem, position: Int, counter: ArrayList<Int>){
        val alphabetList = letterItem.list
          binding.apply {
            cvLetterBig.setCardBackgroundColor(
                ContextCompat.getColor(
                    context,
                    letterItem.bgColor
                )
            )
            DrawableCompat.setTint(
                binding.imageIcon.drawable,
                ContextCompat.getColor(context, letterItem.bgColor)
            )
            textLetterBig.text = letterItem.text
            binding.linearLayout.visibility = View.GONE

            for (x in 0 until alphabetList.size) {
                Log.d("-------------", "onBind: x: $x")
                val ll = binding.llAdding
                val dp = context.resources.displayMetrics.density

                val layout = LinearLayout(context)
                layout.orientation = LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL
                layout.layoutParams =
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    )
                ViewUtils.setMargins(layout, 0, (10 * dp).toInt(), 0, (10 * dp).toInt())

                val titleView = TextView(context)
                val tlparams =
                    ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    )
                titleView.id = x
                titleView.layoutParams = tlparams
                titleView.text = context.getString(alphabetList[x])
                titleView.textSize = 20F
                titleView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.grey20_800))
                titleView.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL
                titleView.setPadding((25 * dp).toInt(), 0, 0, 0)

                val imageView = ImageView(context)
                val ilparams =
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
                    )

                ilparams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER
                imageView.layoutParams = ilparams
                imageView.setImageDrawable(
                    ContextCompat.getDrawable(
                        context,
                        R.drawable.ic_checked
                    )
                )
                layout.id = x
                layout.tag = x
                layout.addView(imageView)
                layout.addView(titleView)
                layout.setOnClickListener(clickListener)

                ll.addView(layout) // here im adding that layout, whit in proccess it is duplicating
              }
        }
```

This is the my fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_alphabet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_alphabet"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rv_big_alphabet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:paddingVertical="8dp"
                android:clipToPadding="true"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="25dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/rv_alphabet" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and this is the lower item of rv

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/cl_big"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginVertical="10dp">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_letter_big"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:outlineSpotShadowColor="@color/white"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cl_outter"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/text_letter_big"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="A"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cl_inner"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="0.5dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/bg_alphabet"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_letter_big">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/ll_adding"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:paddingVertical="20dp"
                        android:paddingStart="20dp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


                        <LinearLayout
                            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                            android:orientation="horizontal">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/image_icon"
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_checked" />

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
                                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                                android:text="Advocat"
                                android:textColor="@color/grey20_800"
                                android:textSize="20sp" />
                        </LinearLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Or does anyone have any idea how to solve it or other ways of usage?

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple view type and view holder for your case please check this link for learn to how to make recyclerview with multiple view holder

[medium](https://medium.com/talking-android/recyclerview-multiple-view-type-abb9c0490ed5)
[geeksforgeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-viewtype-in-android/)